# Dúvida sobre a função rstrip do Python

Tags: python

Alguma ideia do porquê do comando em Python **'i3-7023'.rstrip('-7023')** resultar apenas em **'i'**, enquanto o comando **'i3-8819'.rstrip('-8819')** resultar em 'i3'? Não seria de se esperar que o primeiro comando também resultasse em **'i3'**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tradução da [Documentação Python 3.8.2 Tipos incorporados - Métodos de
>   String](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

**`str.rstrip([ caracteres ])`**

Retorna uma cópia da string com os caracteres finais removidos.

O argumento `caracteres` é uma string que especifica o conjunto de caracteres a serem removidos. Se omitido ou None, o argumento `caracteres` assumirá como padrão remover o espaço em branco.

O argumento `caracteres` não é um sufixo, em vez disso, todas as combinações de seus valores são removidas:

```
>>> '   spacious   '.rstrip()
'   spacious'

>>> 'mississippi'.rstrip('ipz')
'mississ'
```

Answer (score 2):

Terminei descobrindo a resposta: a função rstrip também remove todas as combinações de caracteres do argumento, direita da string até a primeira incompatibilidade. Assim, como o caractere '3' estava presente no argumento '-7023', ele também era removido. Por outro lado, o caractere '3' não estava presente no argumento '-8819', por isso ele permanecia! Fica a dica!